# How to find the number of non-isomorphic binary trees with $n$ nodes?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

A binary tree can have at most two children.

> Two trees are called isomorphic if one of them can be obtained from other by a series of flips, i.e. by swapping left and right children of a number of nodes. Any number of nodes at any level can have their children swapped. Two empty trees are isomorphic.

The idea is to create an array of integers whose $i^{th}$ term will store number of such tree with $i$ nodes.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A000055

Comment: it's actually the default sequence if you go to OEIS website homepage, it's filled in as an example search

Comment: I have to write an algorithm to find it and I don't know logic behind it.

Comment: @terrace: That sequence is for trees in general, not just binary trees.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Is the answer for binary tree where nodes may have even one children.

Comment: @aquibnawaz "at most 2" includes 1

Comment: @aquibnawaz: No, Christian Blatter’s answer is for full binary trees.

Comment: But in my case it can have one children also.

Comment: I have reopened this, because the upvoted answer to [this earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519943/number-of-binary-trees-with-n-nodes) does not in fact answer the present question.